# How to split Shiny app code over multiple files in RStudio?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I tried to split code for a shiny application over different files, but can't get this to work decently in Shiny. My attempt can be found [in this demo](http://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/split-code)

How can I split up my code over different files, but still keep the 'Run App button ' and have 'Code Completion' back in RStudio?

if not ! can i integrate shiny with Visual Studio ?

Comment: It is very unclear exactly what you have done. It would be helpful to provide some sort of reproducible example to give us some indication of what your code now looks like.

Comment: It is unclear, and not really phrased as a programming question. Hence I rephrased it, as the problem itself is a programming problem and one that I've been asked multiple times myself.

Comment: Shiny works in Visual Studio just fine, but it doesn't solve this issue any better really.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that very easily in the same way you do that with every other project in RStudio: by using the R mechanisms provided to achieve that:

- define functions and/or objects in separate files.
- use source() in your main file to load their definitions

Code completion for shiny functions only occurs in RStudio when the shiny package is loaded using `library(shiny)`. The 'Run App' button will be visible for the main file in the application. In the example below, that would be the **app.R** file. So if you want to run your app from within RStudio, you always have to go back to the main file.

### standard example

An example :

In a file **app.R** you put:

```
library(shiny)
source('myUI.R', local = TRUE)
source('myServer.R')


shinyApp(
  ui = myUI,
  server = myserver
)
```

This code does nothing else but initiate the objects `myUI` and `myserver` and call the app.

The file **myUI.R** contains

```
source('Tabs.R')
myUI <- shinyUI({
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      Tab1,
      Tab2
    )
  )
})
```

This file defines the `UI` object used in app.R. The function `tabsetPanel` takes a number of tabPanels as arguments. These tabPanels are created in the following file (Tabs.R), so that one has to be sourced before the `UI` is constructed.

The file **Tabs.R** contains:

```
Tab1 <- tabPanel("First Tab",
                 selectInput("select",
                             "Choose one",
                             choices = letters[1:3],
                             selected = 'a'))

Tab2 <- tabPanel("Second Tab",
                 textOutput('mychoice'))
```

This file creates the tabPanel objects to be added to the tabsetPanel. In my own code, I store every tabPanel definition in a separate file.

The file **myServer.R** contains:

```
myserver <- function(input,output,session){
  output$mychoice <- renderText(
    input$select
  )
}
```

And if you want, you can again create separate files with functions that can be used inside the server function. But you always have to follow the classic R logic: assign things to an object and refer to that object at the position you want to insert it.

You can also source code directly inside the `server()` function. In that case you should source locally using `source(..., local = TRUE)`, so the created objects are contained inside the `server` function. See also : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

### Using modules

If you want to take it up a notch and reuse a certain logic and layout (eg a plot option control panel that should be attached to some plots), you should go to modules. (see also http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html )

Modules can again be stored in a separate file, and that file sourced in the **app.R** file you have.

Comment: To `source` file for shiny you want the `local = TRUE`. See [shiny scope article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)

Comment: @dracodoc good point, thank you for pointing that out (I was too lazy). It's not necessary if you do it this way, it does become important if you source within the server function.

Comment: "you always have to go back to the main file" 
that what i was looking for .... 

Thanks Alot <3 !

Comment: Not necessarily "main file". `ui.R`, `server.R`, `global.r`, `app.r` all can have that button.

Comment: i know that but why it doesnt appear in my Splitted files because shiny doesnt support it ! That's what i understood !

Answer (score 1):

@Joris Meys 's answer covered the topic of splitting shiny code into files. Though one part of the question is to use the `run app` button, which may not be available even if the organization make a valid shiny app.

If you search this question you can find [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/18), then following to the commit made in that issue you can find [what's the rule to have a `run app` button](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/commit/5eef894a336994e0d8afd86c667060f2fe559e55), and [this function about `isShinyAppDir`](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/shiny/SessionShiny.cpp#L70), [this function of shinyfiletype](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/shiny/SessionShiny.cpp#L389):

Basically any folder have `ui.R`, `server.R`, `app.R`, `global.R`, `www` folder will be considered as shiny folder(the detailed conditions are more complex, see source code), then the above 4 files will have `run app` button.

One thing I noticed is that usually you can keep the app running, make some changes then `reload app` to see the changes, but if you sourced other file, `reload app` button will not reload changes in that sourced file.