# Custom UI to shiny application based on type of user

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny application. I have different types of users. Some users require one type of UI, and other users require another type of UI.

I want to be able to display different types of UI for different types of users based on their role.

For example, if I have an application, I might have the numeric input field displayed for some users, but not for others. I might also have the content of the UI be different. Ideally, this would be read in from an outside file.

Note that I do not want to merely hide or show UI that might be written into the code, I also want to be able to call UI code from a separate files.

How could I do this? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002914/how-to-split-shiny-app-code-over-multiple-files-in-rstudio This may help, basically you are creating separate UI files and treating them as functions to be called in the `app.R`. Depending on how you are going to determine what type of user the user is, you can then call different "functions (ui files)" for different user types.